# Passar valores de select multiple por ajax

Tags: ajax, html-select

Estou tentando passar os valores selecionados numa select multiple por ajax mas não estou conseguindo. Ao executar meu código não ocorre erro, mas os valores chegam vazios ao banco de dados. O código abaixo é o que tentei:

**HTML**

```
<select id="admissionais" multiple class="form-control" size="10">
    <option value="cod_01">Código 01</option>
    <option value="cod_02">Código 02</option>
    <option value="cod_03">Código 03</option>
    <option value="cod_04">Código 04</option>
    <option value="cod_05">Código 05</option>
</select>
```

**Script**

```
$('#salvar').click(function () {                

    admissional = $('#admissionais').val();         

    $.ajax({
      url: "insere_cod.php",
      type: "POST",               
      data: {'admissionais': admissional},            
      success: function(data) {                     
            $('#alert').append('<div class="alert alert-success">O código foi cadastrado com sucesso!</div>').hide().fadeIn().slideUp(3000);
      },
      error: function(){
            $('#alert').append('<div class="alert alert-danger">Não foi possível cadastrar o código!</div>').hide().fadeIn().slideUp(3000);
      }
  });               
});
```

**PHP**

```
$adm = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'admissionais', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `tab_cod`(`e_admissionais`) VALUES (:ad)";
$cad_ef = $db->prepare($sql);
$cad_ef->bindParam(':ad', $adm, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$cad_ef->execute();
```

Obs.: Quero salvar o array no banco de dados.
Alguém dar uma ajuda?

Comment: Você esta recebendo um array 'admissionais', receba primeiro o valor usando $_POST['admissionais'] e crie um for para inserir cada item.

Comment: @WictorChaves eu quero salvar em formato de array mesmo (1,2,3,5...).

Comment: Mas no php você não esta tratando ele como um array, vou fazer uma resposta para você entender o que estou dizendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para enviar a `string` concatenada com virgula basta fazer uma pequena alteração no seu `javascrip`:

```
$('#salvar').click(function () {                

    admissional = $('#admissionais').val();         

    $.ajax({
        url: "insere_cod.php",
        type: "POST",               
        data: {'admissionais': admissional.join(',')},            
        success: function(data) {                     
            $('#alert').append('<div class="alert alert-success">O código foi cadastrado com sucesso!</div>').hide().fadeIn().slideUp(3000);
        },
        error: function(){
            $('#alert').append('<div class="alert alert-danger">Não foi possível cadastrar o código!</div>').hide().fadeIn().slideUp(3000);
        }
    });               
});
```

Acrescentei apenas o "join", com ele você pega o `array` e concatena com o que foi especificado no método neste caso a virgula

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi no seu exemplo, se o select tiver 4 itens selecionados, por exemplo, o foreach irá rodar esse codigo 4 vezes para inserir item por item no banco de dados. O que eu quero é salvar o array num único campo, pois ele faz parte de um único registro por linha na tabela.

Comment: Entendi, mas você que estes itens sejam separados por virgula?

Comment: Sim, pois depois num outro momento vou mostrar isso na página para o usuário, provavelmente usando um explode php.

Comment: Acabei de chegar em casa, vou alterar a resposta, só um minuto

Comment: Fiz a alteração para deixar da forma que você deseja.

Comment: Perfeito!! Obrigado pela ajuda e atenção!